# How to calculate the cardinal ${\aleph _0}^n$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am stuck at a particular point in a proof. I would like to say ${\aleph _0}^n \leq {\aleph _0}^{\aleph _0}$ which equals the continuum but I have no proposition that allows me to state the inequality even though it seems trivial. 
How can I show this inequality?

$n$ is just the cardinal of an $n$ element set

Comment: I think I should just say ${\aleph _0}^n = {\aleph _0}$ by induction on n. And then ${\aleph _0}$ multiplied by continuum equals the continuum? Would that work just as well?

Comment: Actually since you only want to prove $\le$, not $<$, after showing that $\aleph_0^n=\aleph_0$, all you have to do is to show that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ is not finite. Since all infinite cardinals are $\ge \aleph_0$, you're then finished. Not that it is wrong to prove that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$ — that's of course a much stronger statement.

Answer (score 2):

In general $\kappa^2 = \kappa$ for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$ (more generally, though provable from that fact, is that for $\kappa,\lambda$ infinite cardinals, $\kappa+\lambda = \kappa \cdot \lambda = \max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$).

Thus, $\aleph_0^n = \aleph_0$.

For an easier proof, recall the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem that if $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|B| \leq |A|$, then $|A|=|B|$. The map $(m_1,\ldots,m_{n}) \mapsto 2^{m_1}\cdot 3^{m_2} \cdots p_{n}^{m_n}$ is an injection, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number (starting at $p_1 = 2$).

For the inequality you're hoping for, however, you can use more basic facts: if $\kappa$ is a nonzero cardinal and $\lambda \leq \mu$, then $\kappa^\lambda \leq \kappa^\mu$. Recalling that $\kappa^\lambda$ is the cardinality of the set of functions from $\lambda$ to $\kappa$, and likewise with $\kappa^\mu$, just note that any map from $\lambda$ to $\kappa$ extends to a map from $\mu$ to $\kappa$ (say, send everything in $\mu \setminus \lambda$ to $0$), and this is an injection.